# All the accepted parameters to add an event in Android Calendar with an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I want to add an event in android calendar in a specific day of the month with title description and alarm active

I have found answer to similar questions that has a code in this form (however I'm not sure that is correct)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
startActivity(intent);
```

What are the intent extra key accepted to specific also month, day, title, description, location etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I know these

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("title", myStringTitle);
intent.putExtra("description", myStringDescription);
intent.putExtra("eventLocation",myStringLocation);
intent.putExtra("beginTime", myBeginDate.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("endTime", myEndDate.getTimeInMillis());
```

Hope this was helpfull

Comment: What are the parameters for the month and the day??

Comment: beginTime and endTime, they are Dates.

Comment: well ...and what is the right format to get correctly the date from a String for example suppose an event at the 16:14 on 18th October 2012... Thanks

Comment: If your string date has a correct format, you can use a [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html). then you can parse your string: yourDateFormat.parse(stringDate).

Comment: you should give me more details. For example If I have this date `"2012-10-18T00:16:14"` how to use this in your code? If I don't set the end time what happens?

Comment: @AndreaF [RTFM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)? try SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"); myDate = df.parse("2012-10-18T00:16:14"); If you don't set the end time... did you try ?

Comment: I have tried to use this but I get always a NullPointerException